# Persist variable in success or fail shell command

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following program.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

(true && { echo true1; echo true2; TEST=1; } || { echo false1; echo false2; TEST=0; }) >> program.log

echo test: $TEST
```

Why the output of program.sh is:

```
test:
```

What is a workaround to persist value in TEST?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using parentheses creates a subshell. Variable assignments in a subshell don't propagate back to the parent shell. Try replacing `()` with `{}`.

```
{ true && { echo true1; echo true2; TEST=1; } || { echo false1; echo false2; TEST=0; }; } >> program.log
```